# Как правильно обратиться к label, привязанному к input?

Tags: css

Всем привет. Есть инпут, к которому через for привязан label. Как правильно к нему обратиться в css? Через `input:focus + label` не получается.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/Alexxosipov/pen/rYLvYB

Код:

```
<div class="input_div">                                     
  <input type="text" id="promocode_input" name="promocode"><br>
  <label for="promocode_input">Введите промокод</label>         
</div>

<style>
@bluebtn: rgb(48,40,152);
body {
  font-family: arial;
}
input {
  max-width: 220px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid lighten(@bluebtn, 30%);
  padding: 10px;
  display: block;
  float: left;  
  margin: 15px auto 0;          
  border-radius: 0;
  padding-left: 3px;
  width: 95%;
  outline: none;
}       
.oute {
   margin: 30px auto;
}
.input_div {

  position: relative;  
  display: block;
  label {
    position: absolute;
    top: 24px;
    transition: 0.25s;
    display: block;
    left: 3px;
  }
  input:focus + label {
    top: 10px;
  }
}
</style>
```

Comment: а что тебе мешает к нему обратиться на прямую?   в чем суть?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Селекторы CSS](http://css.yoksel.ru/css-selectors/)

Вариант №1

```
input:focus ~ label[for="promocode_input"] {
   top: 10px; 
}
```

Вариант №2

```
 input:focus ~ .input_div label {
   top: 10px;
}
```

Вариант №3

```
 input:focus ~ label {
   top: 10px;
}
```

**div p** – элементы p, являющиеся потомками div.

**div > p** – только непосредственные потомки

**div ~ p** – правые соседи: все p на том же уровне вложенности, которые идут после div.

**div + p** – первый правый сосед: p на том же уровне вложенности, который идёт сразу после div (если есть).

Comment: Спасибо большое за подробное объяснение :)

Answer (score 4):

`+` указывает на элемент идущий следом за предыдущим. В вашем случае след. элемент - это `<br>`. Воспользуйтесь вместо этого вот такой конструкцией: `input:focus ~ label`

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZaOoMz