# CSS: не работает нулевой margin

Tags: css

Товарищи!

Подсткажите, почему не работает вот такая конструкция:

```
img {
    margin: 10px 0 20px 0;
}
p.caption + img {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Цель: нижний отступ перед всеми элементами, за исключением p.caption. Что я делаю не так?

```
<img src="/img/5f53d5016e14e.jpg" alt="" />
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat...</p>

<img src="/img/5f6bab41180b3.jpg" alt="" />
<p class="caption">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
```

Comment: Добавьте фрагмент с HTML

Comment: @Node_pro, добавил

Comment: @MaximLensky, img — display:block, а всё сотальное да, обнулено

Comment: Опишите подробно что нужен и более полный код HTML

Comment: @Linne посмотри ответ, обновил

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPD**!! - Вот так?

Ранее был дан **[ОТВЕТ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/740975/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BA-label-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BA-input/740977#740977)**, приближенный к вашему вопросу. На основании этого вот вам решение:

```css
img {
    margin: 10px 0 20px 0;
}
img + p ~img {
    margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}


/* Для примера: */
img {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: center;
}
/* Для примера: */
```

```html
<img src="https://habrastorage.org/webt/4m/sq/is/4msqisjgyk-ate5abefnqlgamik.png" alt="" />
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat...</p>

<img src="https://media.sproutsocial.com/uploads/2017/02/10x-featured-social-media-image-size.png" alt="" />
<p class="caption">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
```

Comment: Да, работает) А как он определяет, что к обычным абзацам применять маргин, а к p.caption нет?

Comment: Если ответ верен отметьте как решение.  В описании скинул  ссылку на "Ответ"  изучите.

Comment: И не делайте поспешных выводов основываясь на ответах и комментариях разных людей, обмозгуйте, поищите, спросите еще, попробуйте так, попробуйте сяк. Если ничего не помогает подойдите к вопросу совсем с другой стороны. Умники и хейтеры всегда с нами ))